# Does this set along with $\text{mod } n$ form group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cayley-table

Does $\left\{0, 1, 2\right\}$ along with the operation of addition $\text{mod } 6$ form a group?

I have many practice questions like this, and I know I have to check closure, associativity, identity, and inverse to see if this forms a group.

I'm not completely clear on how to do this in the given context. Am I supposed to see if $0,1,2$ integers can be closed under addition in $\text{mod } 6$, are associative, have additive identity and inverses?

If so, how would I go about that for this? Is there any methods that would help a beginner understand this problem better?

Comment: Well, what is $2+2\pmod 6$?

Comment: $1 + 2 = 3 \mod 6$ which is not in the set

Comment: So did I interpret the question correctly?

Comment: if you posed the question correctly then, yes.  But it should be instantly clear to you that this set is not closed under addition $\pmod 6$.

Comment: @ayeayemaung $1+2 = mod 6 = 3$ and $3$ not element of set, thus it's not a group since its not closed under addition?

Comment: @lulu suppose the set was {$0,2,4$}, this would be closed under addition in $mod 6$ right?

Comment: Yes it would. $\quad $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are basically asking if the set $\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, the integers mod $6$. Well, the set is not closed since $\overline{2} + \overline{2} = \overline{4}$ is not an element of it.

Comment: so $2+2=4mod6 = 4$, which is not in the set {$0,1,2$}, so it's not closed under addition?

Comment: suppose the set was {$0,2,4$}, this would be closed under addition in $mod6$ right?

Comment: Yes this is a subgroup indeed!

Comment: So for {$0,2,4$}, I would still need to make sure it has additive inverses for $0,2,4$ in the set, and check for the identity, which is just $0$? And once I do that, then I can say it's a subgroup?

Comment: For *finite* (sub)sets, closure would imply the existence of inverses! Not sure if you are familiar with this fact (try to prove it). So here you are done if closure and the identity element are present. Other example of (a non-trivial) subgroup here: $\{\overline{0}, \overline {3}\}$.

Comment: so it's only for subgroups that closure implies inverses, not groups in general?

Comment: For *finite* subsets, yes. Not for infinite. That is why the group axiom on the existence of inverses exists! The axioms of group are inherited by the subgroups, that you should keep in mind. It is the same binary operation. In your case addition mod $6$.

Comment: That makes everything much clearer, thanks so much!! :)